# PHP, взять из массива чисел только уникальные

Tags: php

Всем привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно из массива чисел взять только уникальные?

```
$dec = array (3, 10, 5, 2, 2, 3, 15);
```

array_unique() не подходит, потому что он выдаст такой результат: 3, 10, 5, 2, 15. А мне нужно, чтобы результат был: 10, 5, 15.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функциональное решение может быть таким.

```
// получаем пары [ значение => кол-во раз в массив]
$temp = array_count_values($dec);
// оставляем те, которые вcтречались 1 раз
$temp =array_filter($temp, function($x) { return $x == 1; });
// забираем эти ключи
$res = array_keys($temp);
```

Я написал в несколько строк только для читаемости, можете собрать их в однострочное выражение

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff834ad529a1f3d4a55021045facd8cf85d62fcc)

Answer (score 2):

```
$dec = array('3', '10', '5', '2', '2', '3', '15');
$res=array_count_values($dec);

foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    if($value=='1'){

        $result[]=$key;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```